# Redirect to previous URL after login/register doesn't work

Tags: laravel

I am trying to redirect users to the previous page after a successfull login or register.

I added the following method to the `LoginController.php` and `RegisterController.php`:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
   return url()->previous();
}
```

But it always returns to `/login`. I tried to see where it's trying to redirect using `dd(url()->previous());` and got `http://example.com/login`. Does someone know why this is happening? Do I need to make additional changes in other controller in order to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This method:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
    return view('auth.login');
}


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect(session('link'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `authenticated() function` after login successful in `LoginController`

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return back(); //add this line of code
}
```

And `RegisterController` you `return back()` when create user successful

Comment: do I place that in the login and register controllers?

Comment: Does not work as expected. What I'm trying to achieve is if a user is on, for example, page `/movies/1/title` and clicks on the `Login` link (navigation) and successfully signs in, I want to redirect him back to `/moveis/1/title`.

Comment: Do you have login page or login modal?

Comment: I have default auth login page

Comment: So when you use my code, what is the url redirected when login success?

Comment: It redirect to `/home`

Answer (score 0):

In your controllers, you can use.

```
return redirect()->back()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few options you can use . As Rayan said you can user user after authenticated . So ill explain available methods that you can use to accomplish your requirement.

1.After user authenticated with `back()`

```
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return back(); //add this line of code
}
```

2.Defining redirect route for LoginController, RegisterController, ResetPasswordController, and VerificationController

```
protected $redirectTo = '/'; // You can specify the path here.
```

[see the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)

3.Ussing Sessions

You can set session with previous url and then use it anywhere you want

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
 $redirect = session('redirecturl' => url()->previous());
 }
```

Now use this route to redirect user as below

```
   protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect(session()->get('redirecturl'));
}
```

Thanks